# Magento2 : How to modify the store view url?

Tags: magento2, url, store-view

How to change the magento store view url?
For example **change "?___store=en" to "?lang=en"**.

Answer (score 0):

this is constants, if you modify them you will need to modify 15+ magento core files. Don`t do it.
You can hide this lines from url in magento stores -configurations

Comment: thanks for you ans, I have already hide the lines, but I would like to have a direct url for some product with special store view.

Comment: if you need run special store view for customer group or products you can do it by configurations of magento, just use google.